# String Error : unknown escape sequence: /

Tags: string, go

I have an incoming string that looks like this

```
data-url==\"\/entity\/id\/2439918080\"
```

If I `Println` on this string, it throws an error  `unknown escape sequence: /`

See http://play.golang.org/p/IbURcPc_gZ (comment the first statement and it works)

However if I replace `\/` with `\u002F` it prints perfectly. The actual incoming data is full of such encoded urls. Is there anyway I can print it without having to change it to `\u002F` ?

Here is the actual string that comes from json

```
  &lt;div class=&quot;card2 media-container portrait&quot; data-card2-name=&quot;summary_large_image&quot;&gt;&#10;    &#10;    &lt;div class=&quot;js-macaw-cards-iframe-container&quot;&#10;  data-src=&quot;\/i\/entity\/tfw\/v1\/3298718080?cardname=summary_large_image&amp;amp;earned=true&quot;&#10;  data-autoplay-src=&quot;\/i\/cards\/tfw\/v1\/632987845439918080?cardname=summary_large_image&amp;amp;earned=true&quot;&#10;  data-card-name=&quot;summary_large_image&quot;&#10;  data-card-url=&quot;http:\/\/t.co\/QqWvUQMs5B&quot;&#10;  data-publisher-id=&quot;6721522&quot;&#10;  data-creator-id=&quot;&quot;&#10;  data-amplify-content-id=&quot;&quot;&#10;  data-amplify-playlist-url=&quot;&quot;&#10;  data-full-card-iframe-url=&quot;\/i\/cards\/tfw\/v1\/632987845439918080?cardname=summary_large_image&amp;amp;earned=true&quot;&#10;  data-has-autoplayable-media=&quot;false&quot;&gt;&#10;&lt;\/div&gt;&#10;&#10;&lt;\/div&gt;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;        &lt;div class=&quot;entities-media-container js-media-container&quot; style=&quot;min-height:0px&quot;&gt;&#10;        &lt;\/div&gt;&#10;&#10;  &lt;div class=&quot;machine-translated-container&quot;&gt;&lt;\/div&gt;&#10;    &lt;div class=&quot;stats-container stats-container &quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;\/div&gt;&#10;&#10;  &lt;div class=&quot;client-and-actions&quot;&gt;&#10;  &lt;span class=&quot;metadata&quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;span&gt;2:50 PM - 16 Aug 2015&lt;\/span&gt;&#10;&#10;       &amp;middot; &lt;a class=&quot;permalink-link js-permalink js-nav&quot; href=&quot;\/intifada\/status\/632987845439918080&quot;  tabindex=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;Details&lt;\/a&gt;&#10;    &#10;&#10;&#10;  &lt;\/span&gt;&#10;&lt;\/div&gt;&#10;&#10;&#10;&lt;\/div&gt;&#10;\"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n data-you-follow=\"true\"\n data-follows-you=\"false\"\n data-you-block=\"false\"\n\n\n\n\n\u003e\n\n\n    \u003cdiv class=\"context\"\u003e\n      \n      \n    \u003c\/div\u003e\n    \u003cdiv class=\"content\"\u003e\n\n      \n      \u003cdiv class=\"stream-item-header\"\u003e\n
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please give a valid reason before downvoting this post.

Comment: That error is when you try to compile that string in the source (like it says, `\/` isn't a valid escape sequence). You can't be operating on strings like that in your program, so what is it you're trying to do? (Please show a executable example)

Comment: That string is coming from remote json call. I cannot control it.

Comment: It doesn't matter where it comes from, that error isn't from string handling; it's a compilation error from incorrectly formatting it in a go source file.

Comment: I am not formetting anything. The string is as it is. I am just printing it as it is.

Comment: Please show an example of what you're *actually* doing in your code. That error can't come from your program execution (it comes from the go lexer), and `fmt.Println` will take any string, regardless of the bytes it contains.

Comment: Is it what you are looking for ? http://play.golang.org/p/9bL57jJLeq

Comment: yes, that's an incorrectly formatted string in the source, see http://play.golang.org/p/R3KZOEu_xC. Are you just looking to replace remove the extra `\/` characters?

Comment: @vmovva, thats exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot for saving my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to get a valid string :

```
package main

import "fmt"
import("strings")

func main() {

    s := `data-url==\"\/entity\/id\/2439918080\"`
    s = strings.Replace(s,"\\","",-1)
    println(s)

    //Replace \/ with \u002F works fine
    fmt.Println("data-url==\"\u002Fentity\u002Fid\u002F2439918080\"")
}
```